# Mockito when().thenReturn doesn't give expected result

Tags: java-8, mockito, junit4, junit5

I am new to Junit and Mockito.
Trying to mock one of the object of the class, but it is not working.
The mock method is returning an empty list, due to which test case is getting failed.
This is the code which I have written.

Junit Test Class : Here I have mocked the object and method to return an Arraylist, but when the code is executed this mock method is returning an empty list due to which test case is getting failed.

```
package com.business;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import com.data.api.ToDoService;

public class TodoBusinessImplMockTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testRetrieveTodosRelatedToSpringUsingMock() 
    {
        ToDoService todoServiceMock = mock(ToDoService.class);
        
        List<String> todoList=Arrays.asList("Learn Spring MVC", "Learn Spring","Learn to Dance");
        
        Mockito.when(todoServiceMock.retrieveTodos("Dummy")).thenReturn(todoList);
        
        TodoBusinessImpl todoBusinessImpl = new TodoBusinessImpl(todoServiceMock);
        
        List<String> todos = todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("Ranga");
        
        assertEquals(2, todos.size());
    }

}
```

Interface : ToDoService.java

```
package com.data.api;

import java.util.List;

public interface ToDoService {
    public List<String> retrieveTodos(String s);
}
```

TodoBusinessImpl.java

```
package com.business;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.data.api.ToDoService;

public class TodoBusinessImpl {
    
    private ToDoService todoService;

    TodoBusinessImpl(ToDoService todoService) {
        this.todoService = todoService;
    }

    public List<String> retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring(String s) {
        List<String> filteredTodos = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> allTodos = todoService.retrieveTodos(s);
        for (String todo : allTodos) {
            if (todo.contains("Spring")) {
                filteredTodos.add(todo);
            }
        }
        return filteredTodos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: try to only write code that is NECESSARY. Meaning: there is no point in defining setup/teardown ... unless you really need them! And then: if you are just starting to learn about JUnit and Mockito ... then don't waste your time with JUnit 4. JUnit 5 is out for quite some months now, and it has many advantages over JUnit 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spec says:

```
Mockito.when(todoServiceMock.retrieveTodos("Dummy")).thenReturn(todoList);
```

but your call uses:

```
todoBusinessImpl.retrieveTodosRelatedToSpring("Ranga");
```

"Ranga" isn't "Dummy", therefore your spec isn't matched; therefore mockito returns the default result (which would be an empty list).

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `"Dummy"` in `Mockito.when(todoServiceMock.retrieveTodos("Dummy")).thenReturn(todoList);` with `anyString()` (`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;`). This did the trick for me.

Comment: No need for `anyString()`, `any()` would do just fine. But note: this dramatically changes the **meaning** of the underlying test code. There is a huge difference between saying "the mock should return X for an input of Y" compared to "the mock should return X always".

Comment: @GhostCat Alright, thanks for providing this nice addition, noted for future use.